# jQuery equal height responsive div rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

As my site is fully responsive I need the divs to be resized based on a per row basis rather than setting all to one height.

I am using the following modified code to set the heights of all divs within a container:

```
$.fn.eqHeights = function() {
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.length > 0 && !el.data('eqHeights')) {
        $(window).bind('resize.eqHeights', function() {
            el.eqHeights();
        });
        el.data('eqHeights', true);
    }
    return el.each(function() {
        var curTop = 0;
        var curHighest = 0;
        $(this).children().each(function(indx) {
            var el = $(this),
                elHeight = el.height('auto').outerHeight();

            var thisTop = el.position().top;
            if (curTop > 0 && curTop != thisTop) {
                curHighest = 0;
            }

            if (elHeight > curHighest) {
                curHighest = elHeight;
            }

            curTop = thisTop;
            
        }).height(curHighest);
    });
};
```

I have `var thisTop = el.position().top;` to determine which elements are on the same row but am unsure how I can then set all elements in the same row to the highest value?

Currently `.height(curHighest);` sets all the elements to the same height whether they are on the same row or not.

Comment: have you tried putting `el.height(curHighest);` at the end inside the `.each` loop instead of having `.height(curHighest)` after it?

Comment: Yes I tried this but it doesn't work as the next element may have a bigger height and so the loop cannot go back and set the height for previous elements in the row. :(

Comment: Would having a `<div>` containing each row not work?

Comment: The problem is that the rows are dynamically different based on the browser width. There could be 4,2 or 1 elements per row.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Managed to get this working with the following snippet:

```
$.fn.eqHeights = function(options) {

    var defaults = {  
        child: false 
    };  
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

    var el = $(this);
    if (el.length > 0 && !el.data('eqHeights')) {
        $(window).bind('resize.eqHeights', function() {
            el.eqHeights();
        });
        el.data('eqHeights', true);
    }

    if( options.child && options.child.length > 0 ){
        var elmtns = $(options.child, this);
    } else {
        var elmtns = $(this).children();
    }

    var prevTop = 0;
    var max_height = 0;
    var elements = [];
    elmtns.height('auto').each(function() {

        var thisTop = this.offsetTop;

        if (prevTop > 0 && prevTop != thisTop) {
            $(elements).height(max_height);
            max_height = $(this).height();
            elements = [];
        }
        max_height = Math.max(max_height, $(this).height());

        prevTop = this.offsetTop;
        elements.push(this);
    });

    $(elements).height(max_height);
};
```

I also added the ability to specify a certain element so that this gets the height change instead.

**Usage:**

```
$('.equalheight').eqHeights();
$('.equalheight-frame').eqHeights({child:'.frame'});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It works better than several others I've tried and it's 10% of the size too!

Comment: Great script, just make sure to invoke it onload instead of on document ready when your html includes images. If not it might render incorrectly on webkit as the images are not always taken into account!

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to do the same thing, this is what I ended up with:

```
$.fn.equalRowHeights = function() { 

    var count = this.length;

    // set element's height auto so it doesn't mess up when the window resizes
    this.height('auto');

    for (var i = 0; i < count; ) {

        // get offset of current element
        var x = this.eq(i).offset().top;

        // get elements in the same row
        var $rowEls = this.filter(function() {
            return $(this).offset().top === x;
        });

        // set the height elements in the same row
        $rowEls.height( 
            Math.max.apply(null, $rowEls.map(function() { 
                return $(this).height(); 
            }).get()); 
        );

        // set i to avoid unnecessary iterations
        i = $rowEls.filter(':last').index() + 1;    
    }

    var $this = this,
        timer = 0;

    // bind the resize event if it hasn't been added already 
    if (!$this.data('equalRowHeights')) {
        $(window).on('resize.equalRowHeights', function(e) {
            // add a buffer to prevent firing equalRowHeights() too much
            if (timer) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $this.equalRowHeights();
            }, 50);
        });
        $this.data('equalRowHeights', true);
    }   
};
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/2hdkxdz6/30/)

Answer (score 1):

I took dclawson's excellent answer and made some edits so it works in other situations, particularly with nested elements as is commen in bootstrap rows.

```
$.fn.resEqHeight = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        child: false
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    var $el = $(this);
    if ($el.length > 0) {
        if(!$el.data('resEqHeight')) {
            $(window).bind('resize.resEqHeight', function () {
                $el.resEqHeight(options);
            });
            $el.data('resEqHeight', true);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("No items found for resEqHeight.");
    }

    if( options.child && options.child.length > 0 ){
        var elmtns = $(options.child, this);
    } else {
        var elmtns = $(this).children();
    }

    var prevTop = 0;
    var max_height = 0;
    var elements = [];
    elmtns
        .height('auto')
        .each(function() { $(this).data('resEqHeight.top', $(this).offset().top ); })
        .each(function(index) {
            var $el2 = $(this);
            var thisTop = $el2.data('resEqHeight.top');

            if (index > 0 && prevTop != thisTop) {
                $(elements).height(max_height);
                max_height = $el2.height();
                elements = [];
            }
            max_height = Math.max(max_height, $el2.height());

            prevTop = thisTop;
            elements.push(this);
        });

    $(elements).height(max_height);
};
```

It works with the same syntax

```
$('.equalheight').resEqHeight();
$('.equalheight-frame').resEqHeight({child:'.frame'});
```

Comment: It basically stores the screen location of each element before applying the height changes.  This is because, in fluid layouts, resizing one element can displace later elements in the set, causing them not to be matched with other items in their row.