# Responsive grid 2 columns need to be the same height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a responsive website that has a main content area (`.content-wrapper`) and a sidebar area (`.search-listing`). I need the two columns to be the same height. Currently I was trying to use the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var divone = jQuery(".search-listing").height();
    var divtwo = jQuery(".content-wrapper").height();

    var maxdiv = Math.max(divone, divtwo);

    jQuery(".search-listing").height(maxdiv);
    jQuery(".content-wrapper").height(maxdiv);

});
```

But the problem is that `.search-listing` starts down on the page further than `.content-wrapper`. You can see it here:

http://landpros.turnpostinteractive.com/LandPros_Results_2.html

The sidebar is the same height but I need to subtract some pixels because the div .search-listing is starting down on the page in a different spot than .content-wrapper.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why not wrap both containers in a top-level container? Keep .content-wrapper and inside it, put .content and .search-listing in it?

Comment: I'm already wrapping both elements with .results-outside-wrapper would that work?

Comment: I don't see the .results-outside-wrapper div in your code anywhere. It would work I guess. If not, try to give both divs in your wrapper a height property (height: 100%) or something like that.

Comment: Don't you need to make .sidebar the same as .content_wrapper? Both of those seem to start at the same part of the page.

Comment: No @ChrisHerbert because the mapping part doesn't have a background color. The designer wants it transparent on that section.

Answer (score 0):

If .content-wrapper is taller than the sum of .map, .search-listing, and .search-listing-header,  set .search-listing to the height of .content-wrapper minus .map and .search-listing-header.

If the sum of .map and .search-listing is taller than .content wrapper, set the height of .content-wrapper to the sum of .map, .search-listing-header .search-listing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var searchListing = jQuery(".search-listing").height();
    var wrapper = jQuery(".content-wrapper").height();
    var mapping = jQuery(".map").height();
    var header = jQuery(".search-listing-header").height();

    if ( wrapper > searchListing+mapping+header ) {
      jQuery(".search-listing").height(wrapper-mapping-header);
    }

    else {
      jQuery(".content-wrapper").height(searchListing+mapping+header);
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: Yea, I think that will work. I'm getting a syntax error but that's the theory behind what I'm trying to do!!!!

Comment: Try it again, I messed up the variable names.  It's hard to do this all in my head.

Comment: I see the problem.  Change it back to the way it was, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Weird. I feel like we're super close.

Comment: I'm sure you'll get it, keep messing with it.  I probably swapped something aroudn by accident.

Comment: haha, I don't know javascript that well but I'll for sure take a stab at it. :-/ Thanks for your time @chrisherbert

Answer (score 0):

Possible [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041654/achieving-equal-height-columns-in-a-responsive-flexible-layout)  Author got the [answer](http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/)