# Set equal height and change it on resize

Tags: html, jquery, resize

I have a responsive layout, for which I need to have some divs with equal height, which automatically change height on resize.

I am setting the equal height with this script:

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('.test').css({
    'height': $('.test').height()
});
});
```

Here is my HTML structure:

```
    <div class="row front-rows">
        <div class="span3">
            <div id="post">
                <div class="front-row-image">
                    <a href="#"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="test">
                    <h2>Test</h2>
                    <div class="text">Lorem Ipsum dolore</div>
                    <div class="read-more-link">
                        <a href="#"><span class="pull-left">Read More</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But when the height is set it keep this height when I resize, and I don't know how to change the size again on resize?

The equal height should be set when the page loads - and change on each resize.

Comment: Why do you need equal height at all? There is only one `div.test`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [achieving equal height columns in a responsive / flexible layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041654/achieving-equal-height-columns-in-a-responsive-flexible-layout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) function:

```
$(window).resize(function() {  
    $('.test').css({
        'height': $('.test').height()
    });
});
```

Comment: But this does not set the height before I resize - and when I resize again the height does not change.

Comment: You should probably set height to auto before you measure the height.

Comment: @KasperBjerre, you should use this along with `load()`. How do you define the heights?

Answer (score 1):

use the `.resize()` instead of .load()
http://api.jquery.com/resize/

although for your end goal I wouldn't use javascript/jquery at all. you can probably achieve what you are looking for using CSS `height` property with a percent value.

looks like BenM was just a few seconds ahead of me.

Comment: A CSS solution is faster and will also work if you print your page.